# Can I run the Ubuntu SDK in Windows?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

From where can I download Ubuntu SDK for mobile application development? I can not find any links.

Comment: Every thing related with developement for Ubuntu for Phones and Mobile can be found [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The installation instructions for the Ubuntu SDK can be found at the [Ubuntu App Developer Site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/). The guide currently only supports Ubuntu as the installation host, but since the SDK is based on Qt5 and QtQuick 2.0 you should be able to port (integrate) it yourself to other platforms after installing Qt5 (see the [Qt5 Download Page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_5.0)).

The problem is that you won't be able to test the full functionality of your applications yet, as on the desktop you'll need to run the them using Qt's QML viewer (`qmlscene`), which can run the QML based layout, the JavaScript based actions and the Qt backend, but it could not emulate the behaviour of the application within the Ubuntu environment.

There might be an emulator in the future, but it isn't clear yet when it will be released and if there will be a Windows version of it.

So I think the best solutions for you are:

1. Wait for the first open release version of the Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview and try to run it within a virtual machine (I don't know if this is possible).
2. Install Ubuntu in a virtual machine and develop there.
3. Drop windows and install the latest Ubuntu OS.
4. Try to install the Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview on a developer board like the [BeagleBone](http://beagleboard.org/bone) or [Pandaboard](http://pandaboard.org/) and use this for development.

(I would prefer the third point!)

Comment: This is correct - the Ubuntu UI QML components depend on a binary plugin that would be very difficult to compile on Windows (since it has a number of external dependencies).