# What development tools and languages are used for ubuntu mobile app development?

Tags: windows-7, application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am new here,

I am working with iOS development, now I also want to learn to develop Ubuntu apps.

What are the standard requirement to develop Ubuntu mobile apps?

Can I develop Ubuntu apps in windows machine? or am I required to use Ubuntu?

Comment: i think `Qt Creator` is the tool used for Developing, but which language is used ? and is it necessary to have ubuntu OS or windows 7 will do ?

Comment: which language is used for developing apps, QML or HTML 5 ??

Comment: Both Html5 and QML supported. Go through the link. And ubuntu is required to run the sdk. See - [Can I run the Ubuntu SDK in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/257742)

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu SDK is only available for Ubuntu but since Qt Creator will run on windows it should be fairly easy to port. I would still recommend using Ubuntu because it will be easier. As for the language, QML and HTML are the two officially supported languages for the user interface. You can use whatever you want in the back. Also, I would recommend reading through the [developer page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/). It provides a lot of useful information. Application requirements can be found [here](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps). A Debian based os will still be required to package your app but as long as you are not relying on Linux binaries, you can do the majority of the development on windows.